# How to reduce the number of times useEffect is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, use-effect

Google's lighthouse tool gave my app an appalling performance score so I've been doing some investigating. I have a component called `Home`

inside `Home` I have useEffect (only one) that looks like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendering in here?') // called 14 times...what?!
    console.log(user.data, 'uvv') // called 13 times...again, What the heck?
}, [user.data])
```

I know that you put the second argument of , `[]` to make sure `useEffect` is only called once the data changes but this is the main part I don't get. when I console log `user.data` the first 4 console logs are empty arrays. the next 9 are arrays of length 9. so in my head, it should only have called it twice? once for `[]` and once for `[].length(9)` so what on earth is going on?

I seriously need to reduce it as it must be killing my performance. let me know if there's anything else I can do to dramatically reduce these calls

this is how I get `user.data`

`const Home = ({ ui, user }) => {` // I pass it in here as a prop

```
const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
    user,
})
```

and then my component is connected so I just pass it in here

Comment: How do you update your user.data field

Comment: firing a redux action that makes a request > api gateway > lambda > firebase to retrieve them and then loads them into my redux store

Comment: `user.data` is an array, Array is a reference type. So if you destroy old array and create a new array react will detect this as changes.

Comment: So user.data comes from redux store? How do you get it out of the store, can you show us the selector?

Comment: @HMR yes will add code now

Comment: @HMR have added. it's just a connected component. I don't use a selector. I probably should

Comment: You could prevent some re renders when using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) but currently you are selecting user and the effect runs when user.data changes. The user.data is not created in the selector so it must have changed in the state. You could look at the reducer and see why it's changing user.data so often or in redux def tools to see why actions are dispatched.

Comment: @HMR let me check that out and get back to you soon. in the meantime am I right in my assumption this should in theory only run twice? (once at [] and once at [].length(9))

Comment: ok checked redux. I fire quite a few actions on load. 8 or so but only one modifies the `user.data` all the others modify either different parts of `user` or different reducers. and considering my second argument is `user.data` im not sure why it's rerendering?

Comment: ok done some more digging and realised it might be coming from my parent component. I really need to get it to not call render any more times than it needs to as this is obviously calling it's children too many

Comment: ok figured it out, using react.memo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this scenario, React Hooks also provides functionality called useMemo.
You can use useMemo instead useEffect because useMemo cache the instance it renders and whenever it hit for render, it first check into cache to whether any related instance has been available for given deps.. If so, then rather than run entire function it will simply return it from cache.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but there is too much code to fit in a comment. First you can log all actions that change user.data by replacing original root reducer temporarlily:

```
let lastData = {};
const logRootReducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = rootReducer(state, action);
  if (newState.user.data !== lastData) {
    console.log(
      'action changed data:',
      action,
      newState.user.data,
      lastData
    );
    lastData = newState.user.data;
  }
  return newState;
};
```

Another thing causing user.data to keep changing is when you do something like this in the reducer:

```
if (action.type === SOME_TYPE) {
  return {
    ...state,
    user: {
      ...state.user,
      //here data is set to a new array every time
      data: [],
    },
  };
}
```

Instead you can do something like this:

```
const EMPTY_DATA = [];
//... other code
data: EMPTY_DATA,
```

Your selector is getting `user` out of state and creating a new object that would cause the component to re render but the dependency of the effect is user.data so the effect will only run if data actually changed.

Redux devtools also show differences in the wrong way, if you mutate something in state the devtools will show them as changes but React won't see them as changes. When you assign a new object to something `data:[]` then redux won't show them as changes but React will see it as a change.

Comment: accepting the other answer as it gave me the thing I needed but will upvote this as it encouraged me to look elsewhere! feel free to upvote the Q and get me passed that 1000 mark :D

Comment: @RedBaron +1, congrats going over 1000. It still doesn't make sense the effect keeps being called. No matter how many times the parent renders the child the effect runs only when state.user.data changes.

Comment: yeh, it's something to keep looking into for sure but the amount of rerenders has at least dropped a bit AND the main issue was I was getting a flicker for my animation when it rerendered but this has fixed it. so short term im happy, long term I should address it. thanks for the help, see you on this platform again soon :D